# Proper way to record user last activity datetime in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

How to record user last activity datetime in mysql database?
Is writing directly to database everytime user request a page a bad practice?
Does this become problem on a high load website?
How to reduce the writing load? Do i need cache (memcache,redis) ?

Comment: Have you tried it to see what affect it has on the performance of your site?

Comment: How to go about this also depends on how the data is to be used. For example,  in some cases only recording the logged in session start might be sufficient.

Comment: sorry i dont have experience with such cache (memcache,redis).
i'm learning on how to do it properly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Writing a row to a log table per page is OK. If your idea of high traffic is hundreds of users, you won't have any problem with this. Keep your log table and its indexes simple.

Caching (memcache, etc) will help satisfy queries, but won't help with logging page views.

If you're talking about millions of users at once, you're moving into the highly scaleable realm. In that case you need to be exploring more elaborate solutions. But, get your system working, get yourself some users, and then address that problem.

Comment: Rare to see such concise answers, +1.